# Литература по BDD и TDD Android

Tags: android, test-driven-development

посоветуйте, пожалуйста, что следует почитать про BDD и TDD Android

Comment: книга https://vk.com/doc5180470_444119923?hash=96cfe31580927260bd&dl=cc6a9178f33d83f45b

Comment: @Cypher документ доступен только его владельцу

Comment: https://vk.com/wall-54530371_73

Comment: @Cypher Ничего не изменилось, просто теперь не дает скачать

Comment: там в комментариях ссылка рабочая я скачивал оттуда

Answer (score 0):

**Growing Object-Oriented Software Guided by Tests**

Не совсем android, но примеры на java. Лучшая книга по TDD, которую я читал. Я бы даже поставил ее выше классической **Test Driven Development: By Example** Кента Бека. Примеры гораздо ближе к жизни, рассматриваются "сложные" темы, которые обычно никто не затрагивает, например, тестирование кода, который работает с БД, тестирование многопоточности. К сожалению, она мало известна, а я считаю, что прочесть стоит каждому на определенном этапе.